# Aligning ::before and ::after pseudo elements

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong in this example? I am trying to create div which has lines on both sides.

```css
.bottom-logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-logo::before {
  content: "";
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}

.bottom-logo::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to use absolute position for the pseudo elements. Also updated to use percentage values to make it more flexible.

```css
.bottom-logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-logo::before,
.bottom-logo::after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.bottom-logo::before {
  right: 100%;
}

.bottom-logo::after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-logo"></div>
```

Or, you can add a `<span>` tag then use inline block with vertical align.

```css
.bottom-logo {
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom-logo span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.bottom-logo::before,
.bottom-logo::after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-logo"><span></span></div>
```

Another way is to use flexbox with a `<span>` tag or so.

```css
.bottom-logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom-logo span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.bottom-logo::before,
.bottom-logo::after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-logo"><span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add  float:left;

```
.bottom-logo::after {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 4px solid black;
        width:100px;
        margin-left:50px;
        float:left;
    }
```